# Multi-dimensional array in JSONB column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a model `Storage`, and a column named `data` in a related table is in JSONB format.

I'm thinking of how to store this kind of data structure in a single JSONB `data` column for each record of my table:

```
position | item_id | fixed
---------+---------+------
    1    |   123   |   f
---------+---------+------
    2    |   555   |   t  
---------+---------+------
    3    |    1    |   f  
---------+---------+------
  .. more can follow..
```

Items are ordered, and I need to state somewhere that particular item's `position` cannot be changed; `true` would mean it's fixed. My understanding from [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) is that it should be an array of arrays.

1. Is this achievable, and if yes, how do I do this?
2. Would this kind of data storing allow to create/update/delete a single item of an array? For example, I have three items in an array and I need to add a fourth item.
3. How would this kind of data storing work from performance perspective?
   Lets say I have 1 million rows in my table, and there are 20 items in each row, and I need to get all records that have a particular `item_id`.

My backup plan is just to do some Join table and store all info row-by-row. However, I'm thinking to do something different by using JSONB.

Comment: For performance concerns the best advice I can give is to try it out and benchmark it. What's fast on my machine might be slow on yours and vice-versa.

Comment: Why are you using jsonb and not another table? What you want to do seems strictly relational, another table will work much better.

Comment: @Leito Well, as mentioned above I have option to do it with Join table. So far I've been thinking maybe I can decrease amount of rows by storing that info in single row for each record. Basically we are talking about 20x less rows. Potential Join table would just store all those `item_id` and a bit more info, that's it. It's just seems to me potentially a lot of rows...

Comment: 1 million (or 20) rows is not much for PostgreSQL (for a decent installation of PostgreSQL), what you want to do is done traditionally with two tables, that's the most straightforward way of doing it. You can store the structure you want in JSONB, you can find a way to query it, but  all will be workarounds for not using the right structure.

Comment: Keep items in a regular table referencing `storage`. It's practically the only efficient way if you are going to search for/insert/update/delete a single item. This is all the more true the bigger your data is.

Comment: @klin Ok, thank you. So far I've done everything to implement regular table referencing `storage` and basically I have everything set there. It's just I started to look at my data and thought its more like array so then I got the idea of storing it maybe differently due to potential amount of rows. I'll stay with regular Rails way and then look for query optimization and other things if performance issues rise. Thank you!